# How to target two videos on one page JQuery

Tags: jquery, html5-video

I have two videos on a page:

The first video has no id or class as it's loaded in with a fullbackground plugin.

```
<video ..>....</video>
```

the second one is as follows and does have an id:

```
 <video id="bannervid" ....>...</video>
```

How can I target each one? Using the following it targets the second video:

```
var v = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
    v.pause();
```

but how can I target both? I want them both to play at the same time when a button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an array... iterate through it.

```
var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video'), i;
for( i = 0; i < videos.length; ++i ) {
    videos[i].pause();
}
```

Alternatively, since you tagged `jQuery`:

```
$('video').each(function(index, elem){
    elem.pause();
});
```